# How to display most visited posts of a certain category of custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

this code display some posts of a certain category (pop) of my custom post type (songs):

```
<ul>
        <?php query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'songs','songs_cat' => 'pop' )); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
         <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); } ?><span class="wrapper"><span class="link-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span><span class="view"><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></span></span></a>
         </li> 
         <?php endwhile; else: ?>
         <p>nothing was found!</p>
         <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

but I want to display top visited posts of this category, for example only 12 most visited posts.

Thank you.

Comment: **Never ever** use `query_posts`. It breaks the main query object and also rerun queries. There is no build in system to do what you want to do, you need somekind of custom function to count post views

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so what should I use instead of query_posts.?

Comment: `get_posts` or `WP_Query` :-)

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me how to create this custom function?

Comment: Do you _track_ the visits in some way for starters? WP doesn't natively, and it's a "heavy" (tough on resources) kind of functionality.

Comment: yes, <?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?> displays the number of visits.